# Can irrational numbers be represented EXACTLY in lambda calculus?

Tags: computer-science, irrational-numbers, lambda-calculus

We know that $0 = \lambda f. \lambda x. x$, $1 = \lambda f. \lambda x. f(x)$ and so on, with signed numbers representable as a natural number and $0$,  and rational numbers can be represented as pairs of integers.

So how about irrational numbers like $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$? Can they be represented exactly in lambda calculus? Like, for example, $\sqrt{2} = \lambda f. ???$ (I don't want to take $\sqrt{2} = 1.414213562$ (the Wikipedia page says something the same or similar) or something like that, please just give me $\sqrt{2}$ as it is).

Comment: What does "exactly" mean here?  The usual method would be to encode a sequence of rationals which converges to the desired real number.  See [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/representing-negative-and-complex-numbers-using-lambda-calculus) for instance.

Comment: The problem is, there is no way to encode general sequences as finite λ-terms.

Comment: Not what you are asking, but now I wonder if there is a lambda term $t$ such that $M t t)\rightarrow \lambda f. \lambda x. f(f x)$, where $M$ is the usual Church numeral multiplication $ \lambda m\;n\;f. \lambda x. m(n f) x$.

Answer (score 6):

There are only countably many λ-terms (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346675/what-is-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-untyped-lambda-calculus-functions-i-kn) or [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457537/what-is-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-binary-trees-defined-over-the-natural)), provided you consider a countable set of variables. Hence there can't be an injective encoding of real numbers in the (finite) λ-calculus.

You could consider an infinitary λ-calculus (see [the original paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397596001715), or Chapter 6 of [the *Satellite*](https://www.collegepublications.co.uk/logic/mlf/?00035)). The set of Böhm trees, or the 001-infinitary λ-calculus are enough. In this case, there is a straightforward encoding of $[0,1]$:
$$0,a_1a_2a_3... \mapsto \underline{a_1}( \underline{a_2}( \underline{a_3}(\dots)))$$
where $\underline n$ is an encoding of the digit $n$ (whichever kind of “digits” you like: you could just take $\underline 0=λxλy.y$ and $\underline 1=λxλy.x$). Then you can tweak it to get an encoding of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: By the way, the analogy “Böhm trees are to λ-terms what reals are to rationals” is a classic and good way to present Böhm trees, see for instance § 2.2.2 of D. Barbarossa's thesis: https://theses.hal.science/tel-03886068.

Comment: The interesting part of the question, to me, is not whether an infinite sequence of bits can be encoded, but whether effective addition and multiplication functions can be defined for a specified encoding.

Comment: More generally, there are only countably many [computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number), because there are only a countable number of possible programs.